# In SqlAlchemy, how to retrieve a column only by its name?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In SqlAlchemy, we normally do the following in order to update a table:

```
result = conn.execute(
    update(my_table).where( my_table.c.table_name == "Example"),
    [
        values_to_update
    ]
)
```

But, unfortunately I cannot use *"my_table.c.table_name"*, because "*table_name*" is supposed to change dynamically in my code.

The only value I can use is the *string* "*table_name*".

So I guess my question is: how do I retrieve a table by using its name (accessible by a string) (instead of calling "my_table.c.table_name").

Hope this is not confusing

Thanks a lot

Comment: `MetaData` objects have a tables dictionary, so you can do `tbl = metadata.tables['table_name']`, assuming you can access the metadata object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table_name is actually a column of your table in this example, you can use

```
.where(getattr(my_table, table_name) == "Example")
```